# Google Calendar API get previous page

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar Api to get Google events and display them on my React web app where I am trying to implement pagination with **Next/Prev** buttons. However the response i get only has the **nextPageToken** which is used to get the next events to be displayed in the next page, but it doesn't have a **prevPageToken** which I can use to display the previous Page. Does somebody now how can I implement the prev button functionality ? I have tried to store the tokens in an array but it seems that the tokens change over time so I can't rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

The api response doesn't contain a previous page token.  You should save the data in your system to be able to display the previous page there is no reason to call the API again to request data that you already have.  Just cache it.